# How to implement FPGrowth algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I've successfully used the apriori algorithm in Python as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\marka\\Downloads\\Assig5.csv')
df = apriori(df, min_support=0.79, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(df, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)
rules[ (rules['lift'] >= 1) &
       (rules['confidence'] >= 1) ]
```

I'd like to use the FPGrowth algorithm to see if I get the same result but I believe I'm using it wrong since I don't get similar output. The documentation for spark (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html) says:

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt")
transactions = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split(' '))
model = FPGrowth.train(transactions, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
result = model.freqItemsets().collect()
for fi in result:
    print(fi)
```

So my code is in turn:

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
data = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\marka\\Downloads\\Assig6.txt")
transactions = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split(' '))
model = FPGrowth.train(transactions, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
result = model.freqItemsets().collect()
for fi in result:
    print(fi)
```

But I get the following instead of a real answer, what am I doing wrong?

```
FreqItemset(items=['1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1\t1\t0\t0\t1\t1\t1\t1\t1\t0\t0'], freq=24)
```

To make Assig6 I just resaved my original csv as txt
[image]

I started changing my format and updated my code per user10136092 but still get the undesired output. Here is my code, output, and a sample picture of my new input.

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
data = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\marka\\Downloads\\Assig2.txt")
data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split())
transactions = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split(' '))
model = FPGrowth.train(transactions, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
result = model.freqItemsets().collect()
for fi in result:
    print(fi)
```

Output

```
FreqItemset(items=['Rock_salt\tFlashlights\tWater\tSnow_shovels\tBlankets\tCanned_food'], freq=34)
```

[image]

Comment: Which Python library gives the best performance for FPGrowth? I've been using mlxtend and want to know if there's any implementation better than that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not a valid input for Spark FPGrowth algorithm.

In Spark each basket should be represented as a list of unique labels, for example:

```
baskets = sc.parallelize([("Rock Salt", "Blankets"), ("Blankets", "Dry Fruits", Canned Food")])
```

not a binary matrix, as for the other library you use. Please convert your data to aforementioned format first.

Additionally your data is tab not space separated, so even if the input was correct, you should split like

```
 data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split())
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and insightful response. I edited the post above, still get undesired output. I did a find and replace of my 1's in excel, removed my 0's, copied it to text file, and added the line strip you mentioned. Can you provide additional tips for why it might not be working/example text file that does work with it so i can compare?

Comment: @MarkMcGown You might have missed the second point raised here - your data is separated by tabs (`\t`) not spaces. Inside your snippet you just discard `data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split()` while it should be used as `transactions`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the file is tab-separated, so you should split it by `'\t'` instead of `' '`

`transactions = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split('\t'))`

Comment: thanks, this results in '' being considered as items in the basket so i just need to remove empty values. beginner question, but having a hard time finding how to do this if you have that final quick tip

Comment: should have added, i tried this notempty = unique.filter(lambda x: x != '')